Task :rn-amazon-payment-services:verifyReleaseResources FAILED
I'm getting this error

Task :rn-amazon-payment-services:verifyReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rn-amazon-payment-services:verifyReleaseResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
Android resource linking failed
ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:3: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.

 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:4: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_900 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:5: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_0 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:6: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_800 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:7: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_700 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:8: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_600 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:9: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_500 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:10: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_400 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_300 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-appe/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:12: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_200 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:13: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_100 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-appe/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:14: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_50 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:15: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_10 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:16: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_1000 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/3mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:17: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_900 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:18: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_0 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:19: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_800 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:20: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_700 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:21: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_600 not found.
     
 ERROR: /Users/mac/Desktop/Projetcs/mobile-app/node_modules/rn-amazon-payment-services/android/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v31/values-v31.xml:22: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_500 not found.
     


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
When I building a project using ./gradlew assembleRelease in android folder of my project
